Resonance structure of aromatic [S4N4]2+
In sulfur-nitride chemistry, [S4N4]2+ is aromatic due to its planar, 10-electron structure which accords with Huckel's rule. The overall conjugation for the molecule is found in "the guide to chalcogen-nitrogen chemistry" book. However, is it possible to write its resonance structure?


See: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/237859475_The_electronic_structure_of_the_tetrasulphur_tetranitride_dication_S4N42_an_abinitio_molecular_orbital_study

First, we verify the electron count. Four nitrogen and four sulfur atoms have a total of 44 valence electrons. Subtracting two for the charge and using sixteen pairs to form the sigma bonds and in-plane lone pairs (one per atom not having a ligand) leaves ten electrons for $\pi$ bonding as claimed.
With ten conjugated electrons in an eight-atom ring there are actually sixteen ways to arrange the formal double bonds. Four of them are illustrated below; the rest are 90°, 180°, or 270° rotations of these four.

For clarity the in-plane, outward pointing electron pairs are omitted. Note that there are three formally positive sulfur atoms instead of two, in  exchange for which a nitrogen atom has a negative formal charge in each structure. This extra polarization is in conformance with the relative electronegativities and so may be accepted in the aromatic structure. Replacing nitrogen with a less electronegative element below it in its group would give a less stable result.
The $\ce{S4N4^{2+}}$ cation has been obtained as salts with some low-basicity anions.
Reference

Ronald J. Gillespie, James P. Kent, Jeffery F. Sawyer, David R. Slim, J. David Tyrer. "Reactions of sulfur nitride (S4N4) with antimony pentachloride, antimony pentafluoride, arsenic pentafluoride, phosphorus pentafluoride, and fluorosulfuric acid. Preparation and crystal structures of salts of the S4N42+ cation: (S4N4)(Sb3F14)(SbF6), (S4N4)(SO3F)2, (S4N4)(AsF6)2•SO2, (S4N4)(AlCl4)2, and (S4N4)(SbCl6)2".
Inorg. Chem. 1981, 20, 11, 3799–3812. https://doi.org/10.1021/ic50225a042

